# Using VBA in Word, how can I find a specific piece of text and continue numbering in an outline

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using VBA in Microsoft Word, how can I automatically search for a specific piece of text, remove that piece of text and make Word continue a previous list. I can record a macro of the action of clicking the list button in Word, and it gives me some code involving `Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplateWithLevel`. I would like to be able to figure out how to find a piece of code and then automatically continue the previous list.

Here's what I have before the code starts:

> 1. First sentence
> 2. Second sentence
> 3. Third sentence
> 4. Fourth sentence
>      */R*Fifth sentence

Here's what I want to have after the code finishes:

> 1. First sentence
> 2. Second sentence
> 3. Third sentence
> 4. Fourth sentence
> 5. Fifth sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide some more context to why you're looking to do this?  This code will accomplish what you asked for (as long as the list already exists, and `*/R*` is inside the list), but I imagine there's a better way.

```
With Selection.Find
    .Text = "*/R*"
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
End With
If Selection.Find.Execute = True Then
    Selection.TypeParagraph
End If
```

Comment: I am using a mail merge that adds another line to a list based on a condtion in the mail merge. (If the merge is blank for Maiden name, then no line should be added.) When I do this, the line that gets added gets orphaned from the list, because the whole line is one big field. If I could use a macro to find the line and add it to the list, then I will be able to put it back in the list.

Comment: Is this code solving the problem?  Or is it causing the line to be orphaned from the list?  Do you already have the code set up to add the `*/R* Fifth Sentence` string to the an item of the list, or is it adding it to the body of the document (and therefore not to a list at all)?  Separately, which version of Word are you using?

Comment: Yes,it is working. I have the code set up to add  */R* Fifth Sentence string the end of the fourth item, and then using your code to replace the */R* to make it into the fifth item of the list. I am used Word 2007 and 2010.

Comment: OK, great - I'm happy it's working!  If this has completely solved your question, you can select it as the answer by clicking the green checkmark next to the answer text.  If you have follow-on questions, please update the original question text and we'll try to help further.